# AWS CLI sync error - file not found

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm sure this must be an obvious error but I am stumped.  The shell script below generates a database dump and gzips it successfully but aws cli gives error:

`warning: Skipping file /home/bar/dbsnapshots/foo-12-11-2016.sql.gz/. File does not exist.`

I see the trailing slash in this error but do not understand why it is displayed or if, in fact, aws is looking for a directory named foo-12-11-2016.sql.gz for some reason?

`ls` shows the file as expected.

`vi /home/bar/dbsnapshots/foo-12-11-2016.sql.gz` opens the gz file successfully.

I have tried the aws command with and without quotes around the path, same error.  I have tried the aws command by itself outside the shell script from command line, same error.  eg

`/home/bar/bin/aws s3 sync "/home/bar/dbsnapshots/foo-12-11-2016.sql.gz" s3://foo`

The AWS CLI is locally installed by my user on this shared server in /home/bar/awscli-bundle and is configured and was able to create a bucket on S3.  Verified via AWS browser GUI.

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=`/bin/date  +"%-m-%-d-%Y"`
BU_DIR=/home/bar/dbsnapshots
LOCALFILE=$BU_DIR/foo-${TODAY}.sql
EXCLUDED_TABLES=(
membersBackupV2
transactionReferer
transpages
)

IGNORED_TABLES_STRING=''
for TABLE in "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[@]}"
do :
   IGNORED_TABLES_STRING+=" --ignore-table=bar_membership.${TABLE}"
done

mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="${BU_DIR}/.my.cnf" --all-databases ${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} > ${LOCALFILE}

/bin/gzip ${LOCALFILE}

/home/bar/bin/aws s3 sync ${LOCALFILE}.gz s3://foo
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`aws s3 sync` is used to synchronize folders. It's expecting both source and target to be folders (local folders or S3 URIs).

Comment: to copy file, use "aws cp"

Answer (score -1):

Solution(Answer) -- Yes, Same problem was occurring for me also i.e.  'File does not exist' warning.
So aws s3 sync is used to synchronise folders only not for a particular file/files. It's expecting both source and target to be folders (local folders or S3 URIs). If you put your file into a folder and then sync your folder to s3 folder. It work fine. Thank you.